# Bash JSON string into variable

Tags: json, linux, bash, amazon-web-services

my idea is to put json string into variable JSON, i have a command whom takes a console login to user in AWS IAM, the comand is : `aws iam create-login-profile --cli-input-json file://create-login-profile.json`

in create-login-profile.json is the json following content :

```
{
"UserName": "roberto.viquezzz", 
"Password": "aaaaaaaaaaa", 
"PasswordResetRequired": true}
```

i try to write bash script whom contains json var "JSON" like following code:

```
JSON="{\"UserName\": \"roberto.viquezzz\",\"Password\": \"aaaaaaaaaaa\",\"PasswordResetRequired\" : true}"
aws iam create-login-profile --cli-input-json $JSON
```

and if i type in console ./file.sh the file execute create a console user.
if it try to execute this code i get an error : `Unknown options: "aaaaaaaaaaa","PasswordResetRequired", :, true}, "roberto.viquezzz","Password":`

but if i execute this code from command line like :

```
aws iam create-login-profile --cli-input-json "{\"UserName\": \"roberto.viquezzz\",\"Password\": \"aaaaaaaaaaa\",\"PasswordResetRequired\": true}"
```

all is be ok , maybe whom know whats wrong ? please suggest!

Comment: ALWAYS put double quotes around the use of a variable in bash.  Otherwise all nasty characters in its value (spaces, newlines, etc.) are interpreted to split the string into several arguments.

Comment: You don't need double-quotes unless you have some variables to expand inside. Just use single-quotes `jsonVar='{ "UserName": "roberto.viquezzz", ; "Password": "aaaaaaaaaaa", ; "PasswordResetRequired": true}'; echo "${jsonVar}"`

Comment: @Inian he would still need to quote it. Unless he adds the single quotes inside the value of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put quotes around $JSON:

```
aws iam create-login-profile --cli-input-json "$JSON"
```

The quotes that are there during the assignment get consumed by the shell. You can verify this by issuing `echo $JSON`.
By adding the quotes you will make sure that the entire string is passed to the command "aws" as a single argument.